# Is it harmful to do tree shaking on vendor chunks?

Tags: webpack, tree-shaking

Vendor chunks are suitable for long term caching since they rarely change. But tree shaking makes them change more frequently which breaks long term caching. Is it harmful to do tree shaking on vendor chunks? If so, how can we avoid tree shaking on vendor chunks?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, tree shaking is a determining process, this means that for the same lib version, the code that is unused will be always removed.

So, it is affect the long term caching only for the first time you apply it.

If your code start using some unused function, this will invalidate the cache.

Pay attention that this cache is usable for the second visit of the user, but smaller vendor chunk is useable from the first visit!

Comment: What happens if a previously unused function is used now? Won't it update the vendor chunks and invalidate the cache?

Comment: Yeap, it will change the hash once again, if the content is changes, there will be cache invalidation.